# What can go wrong when an HTTP request is redirected to use HTTPS?

Tags: apache, http, https

How to present it in a (pseudo)code solution to this issue?

I tried to access the HTTPS URL over the HTTP site. It redirects to the HTTPS correctly without my knowledge. Could anyone explain how it works and what can go wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that could go wrong that I can think of in an HTTP -> HTTPS redirect:

1. There's no SSL/TLS binding for the site, in which case the redirect would fail instantly.
2. There is no certificate, a bad certificate, or an expired certificate bound to the site, in which case the user would get a browser warning about the site being insecure.

There are probably more conditions, but these stand out to me.

Answer (score -1):

nothing if you have everithing right in .htaccess file